Protecting user input in a browser against attack
I need to encrypt strings (user input) using AES and send them to a server. It's highly sensitive and it's the user's key asset.
I must assume the browser is not trustworthy and is prone to trojans, surveillance, backdoors, etc. Therefore, the user's initial input, as plain text (though it is not a password), should not be accessible by any other parties.
Is there a way to make the user's input not visible, even if the browser or user's OS is compromised? Would WebAssembly offer any advantages in making this secure? Are there any other ways to achieve this?

If your users are filling in a html form so that you can "send them to a server" then using TLS/SSL is the most widely used way of sending encrypted data over the wire in what would be HTTPS. HTTP is in the clear but HTTPS is encrypted so you need a TLS/SSL certificate for your domain.

The users input can’t be protected by a web page.  If there’s a keylogger installed your web page would have no way of knowing.

If the browser must be assumed not trustworthy, there is no way to trust data send from that browser.

To my knowledge, at least, there would not be any way to protect entirely against an entirely compromised user. For example, you mention that the browser itself is potentially compromised with "trojans, surveillance, and backdoors."
If the only issue is making the text invisible or censored while it's being typed ― then yes, there are a number of ways to do that. However, if the browser or operating system is truly compromised, the malicious actor can likely log keystrokes as well, rendering the previous option redundant.
